# Drawing an Arrow in Pygame

Tags: python, graphics, python-2.7, pygame

Actually I am making a program to implement Minimum Average Latency ( Pipelining ) by using a reservation table...
I have completed the back-end successfully and now trying to design the Transistion Diagram on Pygame..
Problem is that I need to mark an outgoing edge with a outward arrow **(like : a-->b)** but can not understand how to do this...

```
pygame.draw.line(screen, BLACK, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), width=1)
```

this particular line only draws a simple line instead..
I tried using a **circle spot** in place of **arrow head** but an arrow would surely look better...
**Any idea is most welcomed**
Thanks...

Comment: @syrion that comment was of great help... :)

Comment: Another option is do rotate and blit a sprite. You also can render SVG to a pygame surface, if you go that route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you'll need to do is draw a polygon with `pygame.draw.polygon()`.  Example:

```
pygame.draw.polygon(window, (0, 0, 0), ((0, 100), (0, 200), (200, 200), (200, 300), (300, 150), (200, 0), (200, 100)))
```

If you need it a different size, just draw it onto a surface object and use `pygame.transform.scale`, or change the location of the points manually.

Answer (score 1):

Look into `pygame.draw.lines()` or `pygame.draw.polygon()`. It looks like either one of those can help you draw a triangle.

Documentation: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html